# saving text box data to .txt file and displaying the data on another form text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a simple application to capture customer data from text boxes and save on a text file in drive C, the strings are delimited by commas. And display the stored data on a second form which is activated from the first form by a button The code I've so far written is below can someone please help me where I'm going wrong.

The code compiles without errors, but it displays the warning:
`variable FILE in form2 is declared but not used..`. When I start without Debugging it crashes with an error report:

> The type initializer for
>   'InvoiceDataAppGaoria.Form2' threw an exception(Form2 F2=new Form2())

When I assign the array elements to the text boxes the IDE(visual studio 2008) reports an error.

**Form2**

```
namespace InvoiceDataAppGaoria
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        static string FILE = @"C:\Csharp\coursework1\maucha.txt";
        static FileStream outFile = new FileStream("FILE", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        static StreamReader read = new StreamReader("FILE");
        static string line = read.ReadLine();
        static string[] values = line.Split(',');
        string invoicetxt = values[0];
        string lname = values[1];
        string fname = values[2];
        string AMT = values[3];

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    }
}
```

**Form1**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

namespace InvoiceDataAppGaoria
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      const string DELIM = ",";
      const string FILENAME = @"C:\Csharp\coursework1\maucha.txt";
      int invoNum;
      string lname,fname;
      double AMT;
      static FileStream outFile = new    FileStream("FILENAME",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write);
      StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outFile);
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        invoNum = Convert.ToInt32(invoicetxt.Text);
        lname = lnameBox.Text;
        fname = fnameBox.Text;
        AMT = Convert.ToDouble(amtBox.Text);
        writer.WriteLine(invoNum+DELIM+lname+DELIM+fname+DELIM+AMT);
      }
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        Form2 F2 = new Form2();
        F2.Show();
      }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you create the file stream, you use the *string* `"FILE"` instead of the *variable* `FILE`. It should probably look like this instead:

```
static string FILE = @"C:\Csharp\coursework1\maucha.txt";
static FileStream outFile = new FileStream(FILE, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
static StreamReader read = new StreamReader(FILE);
```

And just to have mentioned it: you should really name your variable `file` and not `FILE`. Sticking to common naming conventions makes reading others code much more pleasant.

Comment: Haha when I first read this on my phone I thought you'd wrote "You need to use `"FILE"` not `FILE`":)